# Plesk sw-engine error causing out of cpu error

Tags: crash, cpu, plesk

I have a big problem with my plesk which has been crashing on a loop for 1pm now, this is due to sw-engine-fpm psaadm which is running at 100% on my cpu, is there a way to fix them? limit so as not to cause crashes and that it does not turn as hard!

Thx.

I have already tried several times to restart my machine as well as delete these main sw-engines, this did not lead to anything.

Comment: What is the RAM and CPU power of the machine?